# IOS: Easy Facebook SDK email retrieval Objective C

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

**EDIT**
(Rewording the Question because it didn't make sense before.)

I have a loginViewController that has he following IBAction:

```
-(IBAction)fblogin:(id)sender
{
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            // Process error
        } else if (result.isCancelled) {
            // Handle cancellations
        } else {
            // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
            // should check if specific permissions missing
            if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]) {
                if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
                    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil]
                     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                                  id result, NSError *error) {
                         if (!error) {
                             NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);

                         }
                     }];
                }
                isFB = TRUE;
                [self closePopup];
            }
        }
}];
```

So... now I've got all of the user data... how do I use it?

Comment: Is your problem that you don't know/understand asynchronous programming/execution and you are assuming the above code is synchronous? Or don't understand what I just wrote even means?  If you are trying to access email elsewhere in the program before initWithGraphPath: has finished then it will be empty. Your code needs to   wait until the email has been fetched, when its available you need to add some notification mechanism to inform your waiting code that the email is now available.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond.  I don't think I've explained myself correctly. I've been working on this for 12 hours so my brain is fried. I know the code needs a response. NSLog returns the correct response once the user has logged in. I just need the email saved... somewhere. So that the rest of my app knows where it is. It works fine when logging in with email, but not with facebook. I'll think of a way to reword, but thanks for replying.

Comment: Is your question how can the email be shared by different parts of your app, or how can different parts of your app know when the email has a value, or both of these? You probably ought to store the email in a Model class, other parts of the app can know when that value is available by a) the code above posting a notification b) the other parts of the app register a delegate or block with the Model to be notified when the email's value has changed [ or c) the other parts of the app directly observe the email changing using KVO, but KVO breaks encapsulation].

Comment: Read about MVC. I think a better design for your program is for there to be a Model class which not only stores the email but also fetches it i.e. the above fetching  code should move into the model and the loginViewController calls a method on the Model to fetch the email. Other parts of the code register with the model via a delegate to be informed when the Model has fetched the email.

Comment: I've edited the post to more accurately reflect what I'm trying to do or what I mean. Really I'm not trying to cause any trouble. If this doesn't make any sense then I'll just delete the question and try to either figure it out on my own or come up with a better way to explain what I'm trying to do. I think I've just been working too long. This would usually be easy. :)

Comment: Figured it out.  I understand asynchronous programming, I know about MVC. What I *didn't* do was get enough sleep. My brain was completely dead last night and I simply wasn't thinking straight. Posting answer now. (After I edit the question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.  Presumably you either want to store this user information somewhere or you want to make some immediate use of it. Either way that would take place right after this line:

```
NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);
```

So, for example in my case, if I wanted to post all this information to a database:

```
-(IBAction)fblogin:(id)sender
{
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            // Process error
        } else if (result.isCancelled) {
            // Handle cancellations
        } else {
            // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
            // should check if specific permissions missing
            if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]) {
                if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
                    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil]
                     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                                  id result, NSError *error) {
                         if (!error) {
                             NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

                 NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@&firstName=%@&lastName=%@&FBID=%@", [result objectForKey:@"email"], [result objectForKey:@"first_name"], [result objectForKey:@"last_name"], [result objectForKey:@"id"]];

                 NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
                 NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[post length]];

                 NSString *url = urlLogin;
                 NSLog(@"%@", url);
                 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
                 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
                 [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
                 NSLog(@"%@", post);
                 [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
                 [request setHTTPBody:postData];

                 //[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
                 NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
                 [conn scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
                 [conn start];
    });
         }
     }];
}
```

Done. I just got confused about the model somehow and forgot that "Wait a minute! Everything I need is actually included in the FBSDKGraphRequest... I can handle all the operations right there."

You can do this pretty much anywhere but it makes sense to do it at login. Thanks to Can ATAC and GruntCakes for keeping me from going insane last night.

Answer (score 0):

You are launching an asynchronous task, because of the latency (network, server time response etc...), you will get your 'result' after the execution of your application instructions.

If it's the problem you mean, you can add a NSNotification in your app. When the FB request ends, you can fire a notification and get back the email you need.
Sure, you have to process this late answer then.
For example, by reloading a view after setting a UITextField with the email value.
Is that what you need ?

Comment: For example: If the user logs in with just a text field with user and pass instead of facebook I can use: NSString * email = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"email"];
    NSLog(@"manualEmail:%@", email);

Comment: And it will work. The "email" string is returned everywhere. I'm just trying to do the same with Facebook. Sort of like "If the user logs in with facebook... "email"=[result, Facebook] but if they log in with email and pass it's NSString * email = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"email"];

Comment: Updated to explain myself a bit better.

Comment: Check your variable scope ;).

Comment: I suggest you go to bed first !

Comment: Amen to that. I'm probably going to wake up in the morning feeling like an idiot. But thanks for the encouragement. :)